# A global variable in Phoenix app but not a static variable (not setting)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to create a variable which I can use across my Phoenix application, a global variable that is. It's not a setting static variable, instead it's calculated as the project starts once, and each time the project restarted, the variable gets calculated again. How can I create it?

Comment: Does calculating this value require access to your Database?

Comment: You might want to take a look at using an `Agent` to keep the value - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218738/caching-expensive-computation-in-elixir/35220360#35220360

Answer (score 0):

You need to use other mechanism to achieve that purpose, such as:

- Stateful long running process (you can look at `GenServer`/`Agent`...
- ETS (Erlang Term Storage)
- ...

Hope that help